# There is no semicolon after while in do while loop, even then the code is not throwing syntax error or compile time error why

Tags: java, loops, do-while

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int i = 0;
        do while ( i < 10 )
        System.out.print("The value of i is " + i);
        while ( i > 10 ) ;
    }
}
```

Why is this code not throwing syntax error? There is no semicolon after while.

Comment: always use `{}` for code blocks.

Comment: This code will run as infinite loop. You are not incrementing the value of i inside while loop .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is perceived in this way:

```
    int i = 0;
    do {
        while (i < 10) {
            System.out.print("The value of i is " + i);
        }
    } while (i > 10);
```

The `do` is coupled with the second `while`, not the first one. It’s customary to have a block statement (`{` … `}`)  between `do` and `while`, but Java allows any statement there, including a `while` statement.

(As an aside your inner loop is an infinite loop, so your snippet doesn’t terminate. But this was not what you were asking.)

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is not written as you think:

It is a `do while`, that "does" the inner `while`.

After the `do` the compiler looks for the code block immediately after, usually enclosed in `{ }`. If there is not a `{` (therefore no block) the code evaluates the next line alone as a block. In this case the `while` is "the block".

Then it looks for the "block" of this `while`, and again, there is no `{` after so it evaluates the next line as its block.

The `print` line ends with `;` so the code is legal and this block is ok.

Suggestion: always enclose code blocks between `{` and `}`, even when not mandatory to avoid useless confusion. It is actually legal to do it even if there is no loop (it can be exploited for variable visibility purposes, but nobody does it nor know about it)

Hope I helped

*PS: there is no increment of `i`, so the code will run endlessly.*

Comment: Thanks for helping :)